# CURL post request works whereas PHP(Magento) Varien_Http_Client does not

Tags: php, json, magento, curl, jackson

I am trying to call a Java based service that uses a Jackson object mapper from a PHP(Magento) application. In both of them I am sending the same headers and same parameters, but the CURL call works fine where as PHP call fails with following message,

```
'No content to map to Object due to end of input'
```

My curl is as follows,

```
curl -v -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"name":"john","email":"john@doe.com"}' https://localhost:8080/webapps/api/
```

The PHP Request is code is as follows,

```
                 $iClient = new Varien_Http_Client();
                 $iClient->setUri('https://localhost:8080/webapps/api/')
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setConfig(array(
                'maxredirects'=>0,
                'timeout'=>30,
        ));
    $iClient->setHeaders($headers);
    $iClient->setParameterPost(json_encode(array(
                    "name"=>"John",
                    "email"=>"john@doe.com"
                    )));    
    $response = $iClient->request();
```

I am not the owner of the java service that uses jackson object mapper so I have no idea what happens on other side

Any suggestions on debugging or fixing this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally this worked. The issue was with the wrong implementation in my end of the code, if you refer the `Zend_Http_Client`. Please refer to the methods below from Zend_Http_Client,

```
/**
 * Set a POST parameter for the request. Wrapper around _setParameter
 *
 * @param string|array $name
 * @param string $value
 * @return Zend_Http_Client
 */
public function setParameterPost($name, $value = null)
{
    if (is_array($name)) {
        foreach ($name as $k => $v)
            $this->_setParameter('POST', $k, $v);
    } else {
        $this->_setParameter('POST', $name, $value);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set a GET or POST parameter - used by SetParameterGet and SetParameterPost
 *
 * @param string $type GET or POST
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $value
 * @return null
 */
protected function _setParameter($type, $name, $value)
{
    $parray = array();
    $type = strtolower($type);
    switch ($type) {
        case 'get':
            $parray = &$this->paramsGet;
            break;
        case 'post':
            $parray = &$this->paramsPost;
            break;
    }

    if ($value === null) {
        if (isset($parray[$name])) unset($parray[$name]);
    } else {
        $parray[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

So the setParameterPost somehow honors only the array parameters(key value pairs) and my POST payload was a json string. So to solve the issue, I modified the code as below,

```
$iClient = new Varien_Http_Client();
             $iClient->setUri('https://localhost:8080/webapps/api/')
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->setConfig(array(
            'maxredirects'=>0,
            'timeout'=>30,
    ));
$iClient->setHeaders($headers);
$iClient->setRawData(json_encode(array(
                "name"=>"John",
                "email"=>"john@doe.com"
                )), "application/json;charset=UTF-8");    
$response = $iClient->request();
```

This solved the issue. I am not sure of a better way, but if there is anything better would be glad to use it.