# Magento Server Side Form Post

Tags: php, magento, post, form-submit

I got to get some points for this question cause I can't find a good answer anywhere :P Or atleast I don't know the proper terminology for doing this type of post.

Anyhow I want my magento application to dynamically make a post to a external server. I know Magento has some libraries that allow you to dynamically add values and create a post from the controller or model layer. I just can't find any good resources to do so. Could someone provide or show me a good example on how to set some values and submit a post to the external server ?

In a nutshell I want the user to make a post to my server, I evaluate the data, and if the criteria's are met, I will redirect that data in a post to another server.

I also want to utilize the magento Form libraries to do so, I don't know which libraries give me access to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl`

See

[Using CURL Functions in magento](http://mydons.com/using-curl-functions-in-magento-way/)

Comment: Isn't there a form class that encapsulates that class ?

Comment: Take a look @ http://magentopaper.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-post-data-using-curl.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133563/curl-post-request-works-whereas-phpmagento-varien-http-client-does-not

Comment: Yep I found something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133563/curl-post-request-works-whereas-phpmagento-varien-http-client-does-not